# Heading 1 limited to one tag, can I just use Heading 2 instead?

Tags: html

I am making a site about coding, and I want my page heading to look like an opening function, and then to close the function at the end...

```
<h1>function myCodingPage(){</h1>

... page content ...

<h1>}; // myCodingPage ends</h1>
```

However, I am aware that the spec says NO! I must only have one `H1`. This got me thinking, that I could just style the second one to match the defined style of the first, but what if I did not want to specify the style of either? Maybe I can just use `H2` instead...

So that is my question to the forum... are there any positive/negative implications of using `H2` and up, instead of `H1` and up in terms of accessibility (do screen-readers expect an h1 for example), SEO, standards compliance, non-standards common practice (will `h2` titles be recognized as page titles by any advanced browser bookmarking systems etc...) or anything I have not yet considered?

### Edit: updated since comments

Two valide points made in the comments...

It seems that two `H1` tags are allowed in the spec (although I suspect there is a good reason not to which I can't currently identify).

Also, the second use of `H1` is a decorative element, and not a heading in it's own right, so should not be a heading element at all.

In light of this, I would like to know

1. Are there any issues with using multiple `h1` tags?
2. How exactly should I markup the mostly decorative second half of the heading?

Comment: And what exact spec says that you should have only one `<h1>`?

Comment: You shouldn't use an `<hx>` element at all for a trailing non-headline style-only element.

Comment: @deceze Very true; in this case the second element is not a heading at all; its semantic relationship with the first one may be expressed with `<rel>`, if it's really necessary.

Comment: You can more than one `<h1>` tag, but remember that `<hX>` tags should not be used to style elements.  They should only be used to define your page layout.

Comment: hmmmm.... apparently it was the spec I dreamt up last night. I was pretty sure I read you can only use `h1` once - but then again it might have been a SEO related recommendation or something.

Comment: There's very much an ongoing debate in some circles whether `<h1>` is *the document title* and hence there should only be one or whether it is a *level 1 headline*, of which there can be many. Last I checked nobody was winning that argument. Seeing as it's called `h1` and not `document-title`, I'm siding with the *level 1 headline* party.

Comment: @deceze interesting. I did find a 50/50 opinion split on the internet. It seems to me that erring on the side of caution, just use one, as that can't break anything. I am also interested if there is any bad side effect form just using `h2` and up actually and deftly sidestep the debate.

Comment: You could just use images instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I should have left this thread alone. But I guess other people may need to know this as well.

HTML is for *meaning*, not presentation. The h1 tag is *meant* to be the primary heading. You really can't have 2 "main" headings competing for attention, the same way you can't truly have two "best" friends.

Proper usage would be to use an h2, as it is a *secondary* heading. CSS could easily be changed to make the properties of the h1 and h2 the same, if necessary.

All HTML elements have a purpose. Clean, correct coding involves using the elements in the scope that they were **meant** for. That's why we don't use tables for site layout, and why we use `<strong>` and `<em>` instead of `<b>` and `<i>`.

Use HTML for purpose and meaning, and use CSS for presentation and styling.